# How can I add multi tab forms on admin

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2, magento2.3, forms

With singleton table **CRUD** I successfully created a **form** I want to spread it to **multi tabs**.

Comment: I am new on stackExchange, can anyone tell me how will it take to get answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reference Example of adding demo tab and demo field in Customer form in admin you can follow the same for your form

1. Create a file **Webkul/CustomerEdit/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml**.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
            <block class="Webkul\CustomerEdit\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tabs" name="custom_edit_tab_view" />
       </referenceBlock>    
   </body>
   </page>
   ```
2. Now create the **Tabs.php** in **Webkul/CustomerEdit/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit** as we defined in **customer_index_edit.xml** file

   ```
    <?php
    namespace Webkul\CustomerEdit\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit;

    use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;
    use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form;
    use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
   /**
   * Customer account form block
   */
   class Tabs extends Generic implements TabInterface
   {
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,

        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Demo Tab');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Demo Tab');
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
       if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tab class getter
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Return URL link to Tab content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Tab should be loaded trough Ajax call
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public function initForm()
    {
        if (!$this->canShowTab()) {
            return $this;
        }
        /**@var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('myform_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Fields Information')]);

            $fieldset->addField(
                'demo_field',
                'text',
                [
                    'name' => 'demo_field',
                    'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                    'label' => __('Demo Field in Customer Section'),
                    'title' => __('Demo Field in Customer Section'),
                    'value' => $rowcom,
                ]
            );
        $this->setForm($form);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if ($this->canShowTab()) {
            $this->initForm();
            return parent::_toHtml();
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
    /**
     * Prepare the layout.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
   // You can call other Block also by using this function if you want to add phtml file.
   public function getFormHtml() 
    {
        $html = parent::getFormHtml();
        $html .= $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Webkul\CustomerEdit\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\EdditionalBlock'
        )->toHtml();
        return $html;
    }
   }
   ```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks Muhammad! I did some customization in it and it worked. :)